# leaving sqllite database open on android, bad idea?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have been learning (slowly but surely) how to do deal with sqlite databases on android systems.  Using information I found here:

http://mfarhan133.wordpress.com/2010/10/24/database-crud-tutorial-for-android/

I have learned how to create, load things into and retrieve information from a database on my android system.  One of the hitches was this method here:

```
 public Cursor getClientsCursor() {
        StudioTabOpenHelper dbAdapter=StudioTabOpenHelper.getDBAdapterInstance(this.getListView().getContext());
        try {

            dbAdapter.createDatabase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("*** select ",e.getMessage());
        }
        dbAdapter.openDataBase();       
        String query="SELECT * FROM CLIENTS;";
        Cursor c = dbAdapter.selectRecordsFromDB(query, null);
        //dbAdapter.close();
        return c;
    }
```

The problem was that the above code was closing the adapter I had opened...this was causing the part where I used that returned cursor to complain that database conn#0 already closed.  So I commented out that dbAdapter.close();  I think this is bad in the future if i call this method again.

So my question is:  Should I at the start of my application create the dbAdapter and open the database and leave it open and never close it? (how do i pass the dbAdapter around to activities, fragments etc if I go this route) ... or how can I use the getClientsCursor method as is and figure out some other way to pass back the cursor and be able to call the .close()?

```
 /**
 * Open the database
 * @throws SQLException
 */
public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}


  /**
 * Close the database if exist
 */
@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();
    super.close();
}
```

My adapter code was gotten from here:

http://mfarhan133.wordpress.com/2010/10/24/database-crud-tutorial-for-android/

I just didn't call my class DBAdapter but called it StudioTabOpenHelper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may close your adapter on the
`onDestroy()` method of your activity.

Comment: so it sounds like I open and keep open an adapter for the life of the activity.  now i am also using android 3.0 so a lot of my activities spawn fragments, in those fragments is where i really care about using the adapter.  so if i open an adapter in my activity how can i get it from my fragment ?